# Correcting ''' in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

The problem of titles ending with quotation marks is easily solved with `/mkbibquote`. More problematic, however, is when (for instance) an article title ends with a quote. The result is a `'' '` that should be a `' ''`. Is there a macro for automatically fixing this, with correct kerning?

In the below MWE, citation `one` is okay; it's citation `two`, with the double quotes at the *end*, that I'd like to fix.

**Edit:** On second thought, it'd be great to fix the kerning for citation `one` as well! (Maybe this could also help users whose languages have the quotation marks reversed.)

**Edit 2:** I know that `\enquote` from the `csquotes` package can help this, but [page 4 of the `biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) recommends `\mkbibquote` instead. Why should it matter?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@article{one,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {\mkbibquote{Here} to start},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2000},
    volume          = {1},
    pages           = {2},
}

@article{two,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {But now \mkbibquote{This}},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2002},
    volume          = {5},
    pages           = {9},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you use `biblatex`, you are strongly encouraged to load `csquotes` (and, thereby, `babel`). For `biblatex` to nest quotation marks in the right way, it needs to 'know' what language conventions to follow. `csquotes` implicitly sets it to `american`, which corresponds to the `babel` option and which corresponds to the American convention of "nesting quotation marks in the 'American' way" (not the '"British" way'). You should use the commands `biblatex` says you should use because the package is clearly designed to work with them. You don't *need* to obey, but why wouldn't you?

Comment: Wow, loading `csquotes` really does fix the problem...I'm embarrassed. Thanks, I'll get to deleting this!

Comment: Hmm, maybe leave it as a question, actually. Could be useful to others. (If not a duplicate, that is.)

Comment: @jon Would you like to type up an answer then? So the question doesn't go unanswered even if it is solved.

Comment: @moewe -- I can. I thought it was likely a duplicate, but I havn't had time to look....

Comment: @jon I'm pretty sure many posts mention that it is a good idea to load `csquotes`, but an (admittedly short) search didn't give a good duplicate candidate. So you might as well go ahead.

Comment: I looked for this issue before I asked, but I only found questions related to entries that end with quotes; no question that I saw explicitly addressed the issue of nested quotation marks. I'm happy to accept an answer from jon!

Comment: @jon I typed up an answer, but I will happily delete it or convert it to community-wiki if you think that is more appropriate or want to add an answer of your own.

Comment: @moewe -- Your answer is just fine as far as I'm concerned (+1, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MWE I don't really see `'' '`, for me it looks like something between `'''` and the desired `' ''`.

For nicer kerning in those situations you may want to load the recommended `csquotes` package. (You even get a `biblatex` warning if you use `babel` that advises to also load `csquotes`.) If you load `csquotes` it is a good idea to also load `babel` (but you don't have to).

With `csquotes` you get

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {\mkbibquote{Here} to start},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2000},
    volume          = {1},
    pages           = {2},
}

@article{two,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {But now \mkbibquote{This}},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2002},
    volume          = {5},
    pages           = {9},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Note that if you load `csquotes` `\mkbibquote` is basically `\enquote` with a wrapper round it. I assume the documentation recommends `\mkbibquote` because that command is available even if `csquotes` is not loaded (portability).